# How can I dump a dynamic assembly to disk from a CoreCLR host

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Asp.net Core is hosted in dotnet.exe, and compiles Razor views to dynamic assemblies. I'd like to dump one of these to disk so I can disassembly it and understand how/when the Layout property of RazorPage is set.

Comment: Not exactly what you asked, but have you tried looking at the assembly emitted by the razor precompiler? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation

Comment: @natemcmaster I had not tried that. I didn't know the feature existed. I was trying to determine why Html.Partial and PartialViewResult were honoring the Layout property of the RazorView. In MVC Classic a PartialViewResult explicitly did not use the Layout.https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/test/System.Web.Mvc.Test/Test/RazorViewEngineTest.cs#L108 CreatePartialView_ReturnsRazorView